# Can't start php xdebug session from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, mamp, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I'm trying to setup php debugging on my mac.
I'm using eclipse together with xdebug.
The application runs on a mamp server

here  is my .ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

and here my eclipse debugger setup

```
Debug Port                9001
Accept remote session     Any
```

I have also checked if port 9001 is occupied by another application, but only eclipse is running there:

```
sudo lsof -i :9001
COMMAND   PID     USER    FD   TYPE              DEVICE  SIZE/OFF  NODE  NAME
eclipse   25648   auser  187u  IPv6  0x7c95b5b345ac5873       0t0   TCP  *:etlservicemgr (LISTEN)
```

Any suggestions what I could be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out i was just editing the wrong .ini file.

**This** is the right one

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini
```

I was editing this one:

```
/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.4.10/php.ini
```